# Navigation bar issues on 1920x1080 screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have responsive navigation bar issues. I have made this below code to adjust its `nav` width, if the window is greater than 1366px.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  if (jQuery(window).width() > 1366) {

    $('nav').addClass(function(index, currentClass) {
      var addedClass;
      if (currentClass === "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top") {
        addedClass = "nav-container";
      }
      return addedClass;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.nav-container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 260px;
  width: 1366px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

As soon the window loads the `nav` gets full width of 1920px first and then switches to `nav-container` style.

How can I get only the `nav-container` CSS as the window loads fully?

Comment: I am not sure why you are using js for this, you could easily set a media query in css and set the styles there so you won't have to deal with this current issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@media`, this works for your case:

```css
.nav-container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;

}
@media(min-width: 1367px) {
    .nav-container {
        width: 1366px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body >

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top nav-container"></nav>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```